# error opening sql 2005 database in VS 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, connection

When I created my database using sql server 2005, i was able to connect and view it in Visual Studio 2008.  I then detached the database onto my flash drive.  Brought it home to work in VS 2008 - that worked.  finally when i detached it from home and brought back to work, it will not open.  It is saying that this version of sql server is not compatible with another version.  I forget the exact wording of the error, as it was lengthy.

any help you guys and provide would be very helpful!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you updated your Visual Studio?

Comment: I think you just need to delete the .log files and keep only the .mdf file before re-attaching the database. Edit: unless Henk has guessed correctly, that is ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a guess:

At home you have SQL 2008 (Express).

The upgrade of the database from the 2005 format to 2008 is automatic and silent but SQL2008 databases are not backward compatible.

Comment: +1 for your psychic debugging skills. I'm willing to bet a beer that you're right :)